# Memory allocation for an indexer in c#

Tags: c#, indexer

I am using Indexer in C# but I want to know at what time memory will be allocated for indexer because indexer contains array of object. 
Here is a demo code for indexer.

```
   class person{
    private object[] _demo = new object[ 2 ];
    public object this[int i]
    {
        get { return _demo[ i ]; }
        set { _demo[ i ] = value; }
    } }
```

Now My question is at what time memory will be allocated for indexer because indexer can contains all types of datatype values.

Answer (score 3):

There are three completely separate pieces here:

1. The indexer. It uses *no memory*. It's just methods to tell the program where to look for other things that do use memory.
2. The `object[2]` array. The array is itself an object that uses memory. However, this object only stores *references*, and so it will always be the same size, no matter what you put in it.
3. Any objects you put in the array use their own memory. Small objects use a little memory, but big objects can use a lot. However, because the array only stores references, the memory for this is only the original memory used for the object itself.

All that out of the way, object arrays are rarely a good design choice, both for the "object" and the "array" part.

Answer (score 2):

The indexer doesn't contain any memory. It's just a pair of methods, one for getting and one for setting. The array that you use internally to implement the indexer *does* take up memory, and it's allocated when an instance of the class is allocated via `new`.

Comment: Not that it mattes much because the OP's class is derived from `object` and does not have any explicit constructors but to be more specific the `_demo` object is created right before the constructor for the `person` class is entered.